# Create function JQuery - Not sure where it goes, syntax errors,

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a create function going on here. Created some radio buttons for the user to select either `individual`, `team` or `company`. I want the forms after the user selects on of the three to change. E.g. individual fills in all forms, team fills in only name, company, phone, email address and company only fills in company, phone, email and address. I think I've got the knack of the code down, its just I have no idea where `$('#contact_Type >input').change(function(){...` goes.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Create new contact</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<script> 
function listenForInputChanges() {
$('#contact_Type >input').change(function(){
 console.log('val is '+$(this).val())
switch($(this).val()) {
case 'individual':
$('#nameDiv').show();
$('#companyDiv').show();
$('#titleDiv').show();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
 break;

case 'team':
$('#nameDiv').show();
$('#companyDiv').show();
$('#titleDiv').hide();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
break;

case 'company':
$('#nameDiv').hide();
$('#companyDiv').show();
$('#titleDiv').hide();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
break;
 }
})
}
</script>   




</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Motoko Insurance Contacts</h2>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">What type of contact are you adding?</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="individual" > Individual
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="team"> Team
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="company"> Company</div>
</div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="comp"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Company" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="title"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Title" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="int" name="urstel"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Phone" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="E-Mail" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="location"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Address" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="submit" />
    </form>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you dont have any `element` that has an id of `contact_type`

Comment: @jerome thanks! Could you please elaborate? I don't quite understand :(

Comment: assuming if you want to `console.log` the value on the radio button you chose i copy your code and did some adjustments [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jvtw6gy7/18/) . You need an `id` to trigger the change function. your `#contact_Type >input` does not belong to anyone thats why it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

assuming if you want to `console.log` the value on the radio button you chose i copy your code and did some adjustments [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jvtw6gy7/18/) . You need an `id` to trigger the change function. your `#contact_Type >input` does not belong to anyone thats why it does nothing.

**EDIT:** I modified your `hide and show` function and add some `id's` to the `div's`

```js
$('.contact_type').change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'individual':
            $('#name').show();
            $('#company').show();
            $('#title').show();
            $('#phone').show();
            $('#email').show();
            $('#address').show();
        break;

        case 'team':
            $('#name').show();
            $('#company').show();
            $('#title').hide();
            $('#phone').show();
            $('#email').show();
            $('#address').show();
        break;

        case 'company':
            $('#name').hide();
            $('#company').show();
            $('#title').hide();
            $('#phone').show();
            $('#email').show();
            $('#address').show();
        break;
    }

    console.log('val is ' + $(this).val());
    alert('val is ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Motoko Insurance Contacts</h2>

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">What type of contact are you adding?</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="individual" class = 'contact_type'> Individual
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="team" class = 'contact_type'> Team
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="company" class = 'contact_type'> Company</div>
</div>



        <div class="form-group" id="name">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"  id="company">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="comp"  class="form-control" placeholder="Company" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="title">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="title"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Title" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group" id="phone">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="int" name="urstel"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Phone" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="email">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control"  placeholder="E-Mail" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="address">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="location"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Address" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="submit" />
    </form>

</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

</body>
```